# How to create a view in SmartInspect?

Tags: .net, logging, smartinspect

I feel like this should be very simple, but I cannot find anywhere how to create a new view in SmartInspect.  I've even googled it, but everywhere I look just says that it is possible to create multiple views, but none of them say how.  (Here for example: http://www.gurock.com/smartinspect/tour/4/)

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the full SmartInspect Console or the Redistributable Console (you can see this in the window title caption)? I'm asking as the Redistributable Console doesn't allow you to create additional views. For the full Console you can either right-click on an existing view tab and select New View, or directly select View | New View in the main menu or press Ctrl + T.

Comment: That would be my problem then.  I've got the Redistributable one.  I'll see about getting the full version.  Thanks so much!